# Combinations of Subsets (Combinations & Permutations)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> *We consider the sets $S= \{1,2,...,9 \}$ and $T = \{1,2,...,9,x\}$.
>
> 1. How many of the subsets of $T$ contain $x$? How many of the subsets of $T$ do not contain $x$?
> 2. Explain why the number of subsets of $T$ is twice that of $S$. Use this fact to >explain the fact that an $n$-element set has $2^n$ subsets.
> 3. How many of the subsets of $T$ contain $x$ and have an odd number of elements?
> 4. How many of the subsets of $T$ do not contain $x$ and have an odd number of elements?
> 5. How many of the subsets of $T$ contain $x$ and have an even number of elements?
> 6. How many of the subsets of $T$ do not contain $x$ and have an even number of elements?
> 7. Can you formulate the above results for general case and in relation to binomial coefficients?*

This is quite confusing. This is a continuation to my previous question (can check my profile)

Edit: My answers are as follows: 1. $2^9$ for both, 2. $10$ elements versus $9$ elements means that $10$ elements as $2^{10}$ combinations and $9$ has $2^9$.3. $2^8$, 4. $2^8$, 5. $2^8$, 6. $2^8$

I am not sure what to do for 7

Comment: All of your answers so far are correct however I would have done the "*explanation*" for $2$ as being phrased in the manner of pointing out that $2^9+2^9=2^{10}$, specifically alluding to the induction step of the classic inductive proof of the cardinality of a powerset, $2^k+2^k=2^{k+1}$.  As for part (7)... I expect what they are asking for is to point out that an $n$-element set has $2^n$ subsets overall, $2^{n-1}$ even-sized subsets, $2^{n-1}$ odd-sized subsets, that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lceil n/2\rceil}\binom{n}{2k+1}=2^{n-1}$ etc...

Comment: I will admit that this question is poorly phrased and does not do a good enough job at making it clear what is expected from you.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the statement wants you use double counting to proof two theorems.

$1)$ Since each subset of the set $A$ has a length between $0$ and $n$ (let $n$ be $|A|$), and the number of subsets of size $m$ of $A$ is ${n}\choose{m}$, therefore the total number of subsets of $A$ is $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}$${{n}\choose{i}}$, and since the number of subsets was calculated as $2^n$, thus $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}$${{n}\choose{i}}=2^n$.

$2)$ Consider a nonempty set $A$ containing some element $x$. Each subset of $A$ either contains $x$ or not, so create $2^{n - 1}$ pairs of $(B, {B}\cup{\{x\}})$, where $B \subset A$ and $x \notin B$. Exactly one of the subsets in each pair has an odd size, thus there is a bijection between subsets with even size and odd size, therefore:

$$
\displaystyle {{n}\choose{0}} + {{n}\choose{2}} + \cdots = {{n}\choose{1}} + {{n}\choose{3}} + \cdots$$

I hope my answer was helpful.